Lock screen controls for react-native-video when playing in background
React native video is used to play videos with background enabled. But in background playback it's not very clear to the user were the audio might be coming from. Need lock screen controls.
How do I implement this? Maybe there's a fork of react-native-video that already supports this.
Thanks

Have you tried react-native-video-controls ?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video-controls
EDIT:
Try react-native-track-player for background control: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-track-player
And react-native-video for the foreground. Manage state and sync the playback position between the two.
Use app state change listeners to manage these transitions and ensure proper cleanup on component unmount.

This provides custom controls for the player  UI. I need the controls in notification centre or lock screen like how YouTube premium provides for background playback

Check this package: react-native-music-control - It seems to provide the functionality your after for both IOS and Android. However, it seems like its not actively maintained, so maybe you can also try: react-native-track-player

Any suggestion on using react-native-track-player with react-native-video. I think I'll have to sync up the timing between both and use react-native-video when app in foreground and track player for background

Yes, syncing the two players is definitely the way to go. You can use global state to track the current position, when switching to background, pause react-native-video and initiate react-native-track-player from there, and vice versa. It's a manual setup but it should provide the functionality you're after.
